# using express-session with separate route files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I have used express-session successfully to CRUD properties on req.session.   When I move the routes into a separate router file, req.session is undefined.  For example ...

```
const express = require('express');
const myRouter = require('./routers/mainroutes');
const session = require("express-session");
require('./db/mongoose');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(myRouter);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'thisisitNJDG',
  resave: false,
  cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, secure: false, maxAge: 3600000 },
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

app.get('/test1', (req, res) => {
  req.session.testproperty = 'foo';
  console.log(req.session);
  res.send(req.session);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is up on port ', port);
});
```

localhost:3000/test1 works fine.  I can set req.session.testproperty etc.  However, localhost:3000/test2 fails with trying to set a property (testproperty) on undefined (req.session).

```
//mainroutes.js
const express = require('express');

const router = new express.Router();

router.get("/test2", async (req, res) => {
  req.session.testproperty = 'bar';
  console.log(req.session);
  res.send(req.session);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've tried to research for several hours before hitting y'all up but can't find the answer.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Move `app.use(myRouter);` further down (the order of `app.*` calls matters) ((also comments start with `//`))

Comment: Thanks Chris!  That was all it was