# How do I use express-session with only one session if I have multiple routers in different files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, express-session

Before anyone links me to [using express-session with separate route files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900507/using-express-session-with-separate-route-files), that didn't help me because they were having a different problem than I am.
I currently have an index.js and three files used for routing in my /routes folder, and I *have* gotten express-session to work in each individual one. The problem is that I want to use the same session for *all* of the routes: ie, I want someone to be able to log in via the users router or the main router, but then be recognized as logged in by the posts router.

Here's my index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();


var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000',process.env.DEV_IP]
var corsOptions = {
  origin: whitelist, methods: ['GET','POST'], credentials: true, 
}
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://"+process.env.MDB_USER+":"+process.env.MDB_PASS+"@cluster0.ggboi.mongodb.net/TheVoid?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
                { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(()=>{
                    console.log("connected to mongodb")
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })


app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESS_SEC,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { secure: false },
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: "the void"
}))
const routers = {
    users: require('./routes/users.js'),
    posts: require('./routes/posts.js'),
    other: require('./routes/other.js')
}
app.use('/u',routers.users);
app.use('/p',routers.posts);
app.use('/',routers.other);

app.listen(3002,()=>console.log("Listening at 3002!"));
```

and here's my `./routes/users.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/users')
const Post = require('../models/posts')
//User.find().then(docs=>console.log(docs)) ONLY uncomment if like nothing is working

router.get('/user/:username',(req,res)=>{
    User.findOne({username: req.params.username}).then(user=>{
        res.json(user)
    })
})
router.get('/loggedin',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session.user)
    if (req.session.user) res.json({loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user});
    else res.json({loggedIn: false});
})
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) res.status(400).json({status: 'failure', reason: 'Invalid login credentials.'})
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username}).then(user=>{
        if (!user) res.status(404).json({status: 'failure', reason: 'No such user'});
        else if (req.body.password != user.password) res.status(403).json({status: 'failure', reason: 'Wrong password'});
        else {
            req.session.user = req.body.username;
            req.session.save();
            res.status(200).json({status: 'success'})
        }
    })
})
router.get('/feed',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session.user)
    try {
        User.findOne({username: req.session.user}).then(user=>{
            if (!user) return res.status(404).json({status: 'failure', reason: 'Not logged in'})
            let list = user.following;
            list.push(req.session.user);
            Post.find({user: {$in: list}}).then(posts=>{
                res.json(posts);
            })
        })
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(404).json({status: 'failure', reason: err.message})
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

In my "other" router, I do have a "test" route that works just fine:

```js
router.get('/test', test);
function test(req, res) {
    var sess = req.session;
    console.log('before', sess);
    if (sess.views) {
        sess.views++
        req.session.save();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
        res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
        res.end();
    } else {
        sess.views = 1;
        req.session.save();
        res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
    }
    console.log('after', sess);
    return;
}
```

and I've tried this same copied-and-pasted route in all of my files and had it work.
But when I use the '/login' route, it only keeps the `req.session.user` for the other routes in the same 'users' document, if that. In fact, at first, it wasn't working at all. I did a lot of research and troubleshooting and eventually got it to work by adding `{withCredentials: true}` to the axios request I used to get the feed of posts (but only when using the feed route on the same page as the login route!). Now it seems to have stopped working at all, which is confusing because I haven't changed that code since.

Sequence of events:
axios (on the React page) does '/u/login' or '/login' (I've tried it both ways), returns success
the '/p/feed' or '/u/feed' route uses the `req.session.user` that's defined in the login route, but there's an error because `req.session.user` is not set.

Update: I edited the req.session.save() (which tbf I shouldn't have to do anyway bc I have setUninitialized set to true, but I tried it because it wasn't working before) so now the response is in either a .then() block after it or a .catch() block after that. Now neither response is being sent.

Comment: Please describe a very specific problem (sequence of events) where you create a login session and then don't see it in some other route.  Express-sessions apply to ALL routes that are defined AFTER the express-session middleware.

Comment: There are also error handling problems in your code.  `try/catch` only catches a rejected promise IF you `await` that promise.  Otherwise, you must use `.catch()`.

Comment: I should add that sessions can be made to work for only certain routes by specifying a path in the session cookie, but I don't see that you've provided a path so it should work for the all routes on the same domain.  You could look at the session cookie in your browser and see if it is present as expected and has the attributes on it you would expect.

Comment: I do also note that you not waiting for `req.session.save();` (it's asynchronous) before you send the response.  So, if your client makes an immediate new request, it may be making the request BEFORE the session has been saved which could cause the new route to not see the latest session data.

Comment: More error handling issues.  In this: `if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) res.status(400).json({status: 'failure', reason: 'Invalid login credentials.'})`, you need to `return` because after sending the 400 status, the rest of the route handler will continue to run its code which you do not want.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's hard to describe a sequence of events other than the way it happened, so idk what the first comment is asking me to do. I made sure to define the routes after the express-session middleware. thanks for the input with the try/catch. and yeah my path shows up as "/" when I log the whole req.session

Comment: and yeah I did change the response to be in a .then after the req.session.save (with a .catch as well) but now it's just not doing anything? even though the catch has a response to do as well

Comment: By sequence of events, I'm asking for which routes in sequence a client executes and what the result is for each of those routes?  I want to trace a specific path through your code rather than just try to examine a bunch of code.

Comment: ah okay, I'll see if I can do that

Comment: So, your `axios()` calls MUST always include the `{withCredentials: true}` option because without that, they will not send the session cookie which is required for the session to work.  It seems to me that some axios calls missing that option might be the most logical explanation for your problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I set the default to withCredentials and it still isn't working. I think I'm just gonna try doing something else without express-session.